# Is there an option for us to customize and group the test scenarios in the statics section of the Karate Gatling Report?

Tags: karate

In the statics section of the Gatling report, the tests are grouped based on paths. However in our case the API URI + path is same and the functional flow will be differentiated based on the header values and the request method is POST. So in this case even if I test four different scenarios/flows, all the tests will be grouped as a single, since the path is same. Is there any option for us to group the statistics section based on scenarios/something else?

[image]

Is there any option for us to group the tests based on these scenarios? The expectation is something similar to this. The below one is a screen shot from a gatling.io page. It seems to be a web based application 
[image]

Comment: can you build and test the latest from the `cukexit` branch ? https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/526

Comment: Tested with the version 0.9.0.RC2  and it works fine now. Added the details below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk about timing. Here's the issue I raised a few hours back: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/526

So yes, this is a gap we are planning to address. Counting on you for beta-testing.

EDIT: Available since version 0.9.0 - this works by specifying a nameResolver: first put a header in your transaction and use a nameResolver to use this to group the transactions:

```
protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")
```

refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#nameresolver

Also note that you can group using Gatling in latest version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1467#issuecomment-772609249

Comment: Thanks for the link. Adding some info as I thought it would work out of the box but it works by specifying a nameResolver: first put a header in your transaction and use a nameResolver to use this to group the transactions: protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

Comment: @Andre thanks, I have edited the answer to make it more helpful based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

This enhancement is now done on Karate-Gatling on the release 0.9.0.RC2 version. The statistical analysis will now display the results based on each business flows. So now onward you can have separate analysis for each business flow. This is the way the result will looks like in the new release
[image]

You can also do a detailed analysis of percentiles, deviations of each business flow separately. 
[image]